# How to do complex filter in django with rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have 2 subcategorires of Tipo_Unidad, so I send via get the ID of tipo_unidad it depends of the checkbox selected but I have a problem, When I select the two categorires at the same time I send the ID in this format [1,2] and I don't know how to the for loop in my django view to obtain the query for each ID received.

This is part of my view:

```
    q =  request.GET.get('tipo_venta')
    i =  request.GET.getlist('id_tipo_unidad[]')
    maxi =  request.GET.get('Max')
    mini =  request.GET.get('Min')

if q  is not None or i is not None or maxi is not None  or mini is not None:
        for var in i:
            unidad = Unidad.objects.filter(id_tipo_unidad=var)
            serializer = UnidadSerializer(unidad, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
else:
         return Response({})
```

If I send only one ID the code works but if I send two it don't work, and the django console show this:

invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,2'

Answer (score 0):

There's a field lookup for what you're trying to do - you can do something like:

```
q = [1, 2]
unidad = Unidad.objects.filter(id__in=q)
```

That will give you all `Unidad` objects who's `id` is in the list `q`. You can also span relationships with this:

```
q = [1, 2]
unidad = Unidad.objects.filter(some_other_model__id__in=q)
```